# How to install & run CentOS 8.2 under Windows WSL?

Tags: windows, windows-subsystem-for-linux, centos8

**Question #1**
If I wanted to run CentOS 8.2 under Windows WSL, what would I download?

**Question #2**
Are there step by step instructions anywhere that would show what to download, exactly how to unpack whatever is downloaded and how a directory structure should be organized to run CentOS 8.2 under Windows WSL?

Answer (score 0):

You can either install it through a docker image as [Microsoft explains](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/use-custom-distro).

Or

If you want to build centOS without going through docker:

#### summary

- get a tarball for the generic cloud image
- extract and get the main image as a tar
- import into wsl

#### details

`PS` = Powershell prompt

`$` = inside wsl instance

Install 7zip or some other archive tool to extract the tarball.

```
PS winget install 7zip.7zip
```

Get a copy of the [generic cloud image](https://cloud.centos.org/centos/8/x86_64/images/)

```
PS wget https://cloud.centos.org/centos/8/x86_64/images/CentOS-8-Container-8.3.2011-20201204.2.x86_64.tar.xz
```

Extract `layer.tar`

```
PS 7z e CentOS-8-Container-8.3.2011-20201204.x86_64.tar.xz
```

```
# Create an install location
PS mkdir C:\wsl\centOS8
# bring in to wsl
# wsl --import wsl-name pathToInstallWSLImage pathToExtratedTar
# make sure `layer.tar` is linked
PS wsl --import centOS8 C:\wsl\CentOS8 .\path\to\previously\extracted\layer.tar
# list images
PS wsl -l -v
# set as default (optional)
PS wsl --set-default centOS8
# run it
PS wsl -d centOS8
```

Now within centOS

```
# install a few dependencies mostly for user management
$ dnf install dnf-plugins-core dnf-utils findutils sudo passwd cracklib cracklib-dicts
# configure a user {youruser}
$ useradd -G wheel youruser
$ passwd
> enter a password
$ exit
```

Back to powershell

```
# log in to wsl as youruser
PS wsl -d centOS8 -u youruser
# in centOS
$ id -u
1000
# in powershell set default user for wsl, match id from previous step
PS Get-ItemProperty Registry::HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Lxss\*\ DistributionName | Where-Object -Property DistributionName -eq centOS8  | Set-ItemProperty -Name DefaultUid -Value 1000
# logging back in should default to the newly created user
PS wsl
[youruser@host wsl]$
```

Customize from there.